# How can I solve an error while importing a component in a Reacjs project?

Tags: reactjs

I'm facing a weird behavior. I say weird, because after creating a new branch and recompiling my project, one of the oldest imports of my project, starts failing.

I'm using a default export in the following file:

[image]

PS: I show the collapsed format as there's no point to show too much code...

I do the same for this another component:

[image]

No differences here...

Each component is independent from others in the project. So to make them visible in the project and as they have some other components in their main folder, I use an `index.js` file to export just the main component, like this:

[image]

[image]

And both components are imported in the same file:

[image]

Everything looks the same! right?... But today I started to see this while recompiling the project:

[image]

I don't see any differences between them... and compilation fails just because of the `Objection` component... I'm struggling with this for a couple of hours... but it has no sense.

Any idea on what is wrong? What's missing?

Comment: Could you add the file structure? Is the full filepath to the `Complete` component `components/Complete/Complete.jsx`? It may be also be worth having a `jsconfig` file to help point to the `src` directory (https://dev.to/isiakaabd/configuring-absolute-path-in-react-projects-4h9o#:~:text=How%20to%20Configure%20Absolute%20Path%20in%20Create%2DReact%2DApp)

Answer (score 0):

I think you should write imports like this:

```
import { Objection, Complete } from "./components"
```

if index.js is located in components folder

edit:
you are importing components from files where they were exported as default

Comment: They are at a different folder level. So no, index is not located at components level... I'm trying to do it like that to make any Component as extendible and independent as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I reinstalled everything and is working again... :( No idea why